# hidden element will not send correct data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have model :

```
 Public class delimg
   {

   Public long idparrent {get ; set}
   Public long nameimg {get; set}
    }
```

In view :

```
  @foreach ( var item in ....myclass (  model.idparrent).tolist ())

  {
  <img  id="@( item.imagename)" />
  @html.hidden ("nameimg" , item.imagename)

<button > click </button>
  }
```

It makes some hidden elements with correct values .  But when click on button always first item will be sent to controller. For example if we have 11.jpg  , sim.jpg , ac.jpg , always 11.jpg will send .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By name of the class (delimg) you want to delete selected image, right? You can simply generate url to delete action to the button (or anchor):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "YourImageController", new { nameimg = item.nameimg })">Delete</a>
```